# Most Winning Runs in ICC T20 Cricket History

Tags: cricket, icc, cricket-world-cup

Which **T20 cricketer** has hit the most winning run in ICC ?

Comment: Its unclear. What is the meaning of winning run Exactly?

Comment: Winning run means the last winning shot of the match and only applicable for 2nd batting.

Comment: What do you mean by icc? Are you referring any International match organized by ICC or the ICC World T20?